# Directly upload a video to youtube by pure PHP and OAuth

Tags: php, youtube

I just want to send a POST request to YouTube's server to upload a video directly to YouTube via OAuth.

I have an access token and developer key - how could I send a POST request from PHP to YouTube's gdata server?

The POST request I want to send is found here: [Sending an Upload API Request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading)

```
POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY
Slug: VIDEO_FILENAME
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="BOUNDARY_STRING"
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Connection: close

--<boundary_string>
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

API_XML_request
--BOUNDARY_STRING
Content-Type: VIDEO_CONTENT_TYPE
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<Binary File Data>
--BOUNDARY_STRING--
```

I tried the below function, and a lot more like it, but it can't send the XML part of the above mentioned POST request.

```
if (!function_exists('send_post_request'))
{
    function send_post_request($url, $data)
    {
        $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST',
                                                               'content' => http_build_query($data))));
        $result  = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I also tried cURL!

Comment: What have you tried? Information on how to send a POST request with PHP can be found with [a simple Google search](http://google.com/search?q=php+send+post+request). Did you try that? What did you find, what didn't work? You need to show some effort.

Comment: ProTip™: Adding insulting text to the beginning of your question doesn't improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I already tried it, I also tried Zend's Gdata API, and I'm stuck at the part where the post request must send an XML file to the server, thank you for atleast replying

Comment: Edit your question using the link at the bottom and add what code you tried and what problems you had with it, please.

Comment: It must be a very easy question for a PHP addict, my problem is that I can send the post request(with Curl and fSockOpen) buw I can't tell myself that I did it right or not!

Comment: Okay - so add the code to your question, and we can help you.

Comment: Okay! You now have a good question, and I withdrew my -1. Congratulations. (Also, sorry, but I don't know how to answer this one `=)`)

Comment: It's ok! I'll be wasting more time for finding a perfect solution, anyway thank you! `:'(`

Comment: IamAditya, keep your communications on this site as professional as possible. Not every question will receive an answer, especially one which may need someone to answer who has specific experience. You're lucky @minitech didn't flag this to close, but he's a kind friendly sort. Try to return the sentiment. `:)`

Comment: thanks for your kindness `:/` , I'm sorry for my reaction!